# SVG icon mouseover animation

Tags: html, css, svg, icons, css-animations

I'm creating a webpage with the below SVG which is a combination of two different SVG icon's code.

I want to change the visibility of icons from visible to hidden and vice versa upon `mouseover`.

Below CSS I've written for the same, but it is not working.

```css
#icon1:hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#icon2:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="#E0EADF" class="bi bi-emoji-smile mr-2" viewBox="0 0 17 17" style="position: relative;top: 0px;left: 0px;">
  <path visibility="visible" d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
  <path visibility="visible" id="icon1" d="M4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zm4 0c0 .828-.448 1.5-1 1.5s-1-.672-1-1.5S9.448 5 10 5s1 .672 1 1.5z"/>
  <path visibility="hidden" id="icon2" d="M4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zm1.757-.437a.5.5 0 0 1 .68.194.934.934 0 0 0 .813.493c.339 0 .645-.19.813-.493a.5.5 0 1 1 .874.486A1.934 1.934 0 0 1 10.25 7.75c-.73 0-1.356-.412-1.687-1.007a.5.5 0 0 1 .194-.68z"/>
</svg>
```

Can you please guide me on how to achieve this? Also is it possible to create a CSS animation so that the visibility will be changed infinitely with 5s interval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add svg infront :

```css
svg:hover #icon1{
  visibility: hidden;
}
svg:hover #icon2{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="violet" class="bi bi-emoji-smile mr-2" viewBox="0 0 17 17" style="position: relative;top: 0px;left: 0px;">
          <path visibility="visible" d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
          <path visibility="visible" id="icon1" d="M4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zm4 0c0 .828-.448 1.5-1 1.5s-1-.672-1-1.5S9.448 5 10 5s1 .672 1 1.5z"/>
          <path visibility="hidden" id="icon2" d="M4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zm1.757-.437a.5.5 0 0 1 .68.194.934.934 0 0 0 .813.493c.339 0 .645-.19.813-.493a.5.5 0 1 1 .874.486A1.934 1.934 0 0 1 10.25 7.75c-.73 0-1.356-.412-1.687-1.007a.5.5 0 0 1 .194-.68z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine but once you set `visibility` to hidden you are no longer hovering. Perhaps use stroke color transparent instead?

Then add a transition.

```css
svg {
  height: 90vh;
  display: block;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

svg path {
  stroke: red;
  fill: none;
  transition: stroke 1s ease;
}

#icon1:hover,
#icon2:hover {
  stroke: transparent;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#E0EADF" class="bi bi-emoji-smile mr-2" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
          <path  d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
          <path id="icon1" d="M4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zm4 0c0 .828-.448 1.5-1 1.5s-1-.672-1-1.5S9.448 5 10 5s1 .672 1 1.5z"/>
          <path visibility="hidden" id="icon2" d="M4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zm1.757-.437a.5.5 0 0 1 .68.194.934.934 0 0 0 .813.493c.339 0 .645-.19.813-.493a.5.5 0 1 1 .874.486A1.934 1.934 0 0 1 10.25 7.75c-.73 0-1.356-.412-1.687-1.007a.5.5 0 0 1 .194-.68z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

For CSS animation to change the visibility of icon try below

```css
.icon_animate_1{
  animation: icon_frame1 3s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes icon_frame1{
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  90% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.icon_animate_2{
  animation: icon_frame2 3s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes icon_frame2{
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  90% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="#5F77F1" class="bi bi-emoji-smile mr-2" viewBox="0 0 17 17">
          <path visibility="visible" d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
          <path class="icon_animate_1" d="M4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zm4 0c0 .828-.448 1.5-1 1.5s-1-.672-1-1.5S9.448 5 10 5s1 .672 1 1.5z"/>
          <path class="icon_animate_2" d="M4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zm1.757-.437a.5.5 0 0 1 .68.194.934.934 0 0 0 .813.493c.339 0 .645-.19.813-.493a.5.5 0 1 1 .874.486A1.934 1.934 0 0 1 10.25 7.75c-.73 0-1.356-.412-1.687-1.007a.5.5 0 0 1 .194-.68z"/>
</svg>
```